# Recognize when user position remains unchanged with coordinates log file

Tags: android, position, interpolation

I'm developing an application used for the outdoor's sports like bike or jogging, that collect the coordinates as pairs of latitude / longitude, and store them in a .xml file.
As i saw, coordinates changes even if the device is perfectly standing on the floor, but i need to understand when user temporarly stop his session without using the activity recogniser's API, no matter if client side with android, or server side using a php script, because i need to remove the still time, path, meters etc from the training session.
This is an example of a graphical representation of a perfectly standing device:

[image: example pic]

some idea?

Comment: If you want the app to stop collecting positions if standing still, you can use the accelerometer to determine this. I have sample code if this is correctly understood.

Comment: i already do this for the jogging, but still need to do what i described for others kind of sports, btw can you show me your samples?

Answer (score 0):

I currently follow a course called Pervasive Positioning where one of the hand ins was an Android project that uses different algorithms for determining locations. Both server and client side.

The project is uploaded here: [cyrixmorten.net/PP-Project2.zip](http://cyrixmorten.net/PP-Project2.zip)

It can be imported as an existing android project and should run on most devices. I have removed some code from where the locations are uploaded (mmm.location.logging.UploaderThread) as we used a private server for this purpose. The same data is saved locally on the device (though not converted to KML).

The relevant code for each strategy is found in the mmm.location.strategy.impl package.

You will also find a report folder with a pdf containing a description of the algorithms.

Perhaps some of the concepts could be useful for your application.